# Python Formatting - Break up long line caused by indexing

Tags: python, formatting

I have a line accessing a very nested attribute in a dictionary that is now failing a PEP8 checker that was recently added to our release pipeline.

For example:

`nested_attr = d['long_attr_name_1']['long_attr_name_2']['long_attr_name_3']['you_get_the_point']`

What is the pythonic way to break up a line like this so it does not exceed the style guide line limit check?

Comment: Adding '\' at the end of each line or wrapping the whole statement in brackets.

Answer (score 2):

```
nested_attr = (d['long_attr_name_1']['long_attr_name_2']
                ['long_attr_name_3']['you_get_the_point'])
```

Wrapping in brackets if a PEP8 saviour!